# Why did I get an error about using memory keyword in function getname?

Tags: remix, memory, calldata

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract s12 {
    uint public age;
    string public name;
    bool rollno;
    
    constructor() public {
        rollno= false;
    }

    function setname(string memory newName) public {
      name=newName;
    }

    function  getname() public view returns (string){
      return name;
    }

    function setAge(string  memory newAge) public {
      age=newAge;
    }

    function getAge() public view returns(uint){
      return age;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two remarks here:

1. In function getname(), you just need to add `memory` in the returned value:

   ```
   function  getName() public view returns (string memory) {..}
   ```
2. You have a type mismatch in function setAge(), as you are assigning newAge (string) to age (uint). The newAge parameter should be `uint` as well.

   ```
   function setAge(uint  newAge) public {
      age = newAge;
   }
   ```